# Can I say “years passed” in specific usage

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

I am sure I’ve seen this usage somewhere, i want to use this and it goes like this:

“As I reflect on the years passed, ...”

I don’t feel comfortable with it. But I’ve seen similar usage in “ a reflection on years passed”

Can someone help tell if my usage is correct ?

Thanks

Comment: That's a good example of prose, Mario. It's correct. Are you writing something?

Comment: Yup I’m writing a “goodbye” mail to my colleagues as I’m resigning. My sentence goes like this - “ As I sit on my desk one last time and reflect on the years passed, I have no regrets.”

Comment: @Matt I think you need to check your sources.

Comment: Ronald, I think it's fine prose. We passed time together. Not we past time time together. I remember the times passed, laughs shared, the lessons learned. Btw, Mario: sit AT your desk-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct English.

Confusion often arises between the verb **passed**

> She passed the library each morning on the way to work

and the word **past** which, problematically, while never a verb,
can act as a noun:

> The reason for his actions lay in his past

or a preposition:

> The first horse past the post

or an adverb:

> Several dogs ran past

or an adjective:

> The past week has been a busy one.

In your case your are talking about **the years past** where **past** is an adjective. That's to say, earlier years or years that have gone by.

To use your construction, you would have to change it to read:

> As I reflect on the years **that have passed** since.....

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/past

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/past_1

https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/past.htm

Comment: Thanks @Ronald, I got it. But what abt usages where they say , “ ghosts of new years past” ?

Comment: @MarioSilva Whether **past years** or **years past** you're talking about the same thing. **Past** is an adjective describing **years** as **previous** would be. Otherwise, you might write: **Ghosts of years past passed by** to see how both words could be used.

Answer (score -1):

passed / past

> If you are referring to a distance or a period of time before now, use “past”: “the police car drove past the suspect’s house” (distance) or “the team performed well in the past” (time). If you are describing the action of passing, however, you need to use “passed”: “when John passed the gravy, he spilled it on his lap,” “the teacher was astonished that none of the students had passed the test,” “after a brief illness, he passed away.” Remember that no matter however you have ”passed the time” you have never “past the time,” not even in the distant past.
>
> “Past” can be an adjective, a noun, a preposition, or an adverb, but never a verb. If you need to write the past tense of the verb “to pass,” use “passed.”

Published in Prof Paul Brian’s book,
Common Errors of English Usage

https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/30/passed-past/

Comment: Thank you so much, Everyone! I'm done with the write-up and resigned from my job. It is so liberating !